# Spring - Null pointer exception when using HttpHeaders with @RequestHeaders

Tags: java, spring, http-headers

I am not familiar with spring, but I am running into this issue where I am running into a nullpointerexception at `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver.java:72)`

I was able to randomly figure out that it is this `@RequestHeader` annotation that is causing the issue, but cannot figure out why. The weird thing is that it doesn't even look like the `HttpHeaders` object that is returned isn't even being used in the function. I did a quick search but couldn't really find whether this annotation is even necessary for the function. Here is the original code for handling the request with this problem

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webforms/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView prepareView(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value="signoffId", required=false) Integer signoffId, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
    clearErrorsForNewRequest(request);
    return prepareView(request, VIEW, signoffId);
}
```

I tried to use `@RequestHeaders` without `HttpHeaders` like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webforms/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView prepareView(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value="signoffId", required=false) Integer signoffId, @RequestHeader String host) {
    clearErrorsForNewRequest(request);
    return prepareView(request, VIEW, signoffId);
}
```

and I no longer get this exception. What is going on here? I can clearly see the http headers when i make my request, why am i getting this exception in Spring? Is there some restrictions on what kind of requests that can use the `HttpHeaders` object ???

See below for what my request header looks like:

[image: This is what my request header for the request looks like]

This seems to be the problematic section I retrieved from a decompiler with the exception being thrown on line 72. It looks like the nullpointerexception might be coming from `webRequest` but it is clearly not throwing an exception on line 70

```
/* 70 */       for (Iterator<String> iterator = 
webRequest.getHeaderNames(); iterator.hasNext();) {
/* 71 */         String headerName = (String)iterator.next();
/* 72 */         for (String headerValue : webRequest.getHeaderValues(headerName)) {
/* 73 */           result.add(headerName, headerValue);
/*    */         }
/*    */       }
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpHeaders can be used to be put in ResponseEntity object as return value of the controller method. Parameters of this type are not automatically created by Spring. There are lot of other classes that can be used. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments

Maybe you take WebRequest as method param and WebRequest#getHeader to get the specific header value inside your method.

Comment: In this case it seems like `headers` is not even used, regardless of whether `request.getHeader` is used or not? It looks that way to me but I don't know enough about spring and I assume there must have been a reason why the initial PR was written this way

Comment: Try to remove the annotation @RequestHeader with HttpHeaders param

Comment: yes, i know this solves the problem. But I am curious if there is some issue with the way my headers are formatted that may be causing this exception